# React testing library fireEvent not firing / found answer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I have an issue with using react testing library and its fireEvent function.
I want to test my component and its style after hovering.
Here it is my component written in tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'
import Paper, { PaperProps } from '@material-ui/core/Paper'
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box'
import posed from 'react-pose'
import grey from '@material-ui/core/colors/grey'
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green'
import lightBlue from '@material-ui/core/colors/lightBlue'
import teal from '@material-ui/core/colors/teal'

function styleProducer(variant: BigTileProps['variant'] = 'default', color: BigTileProps['color'] = 'default'): Function {
    type colrMapType = {
        [k: string]: { tile: { [pr: string]: string } }
    }
    const colorMap: colrMapType = {
        default: { tile: {} },
        grey: {
            tile: { background: grey[700], color: 'white' }
        },
        green: {
            tile: { background: green[300] }
        },
        teal: {
            tile: { background: teal[400], color: 'white' }
        },
        blue: {
            tile: { background: lightBlue[200] }
        },
    }
    interface variantsKeys {
        small: (theme: any) => object
        default: (theme: any) => object
        big: (theme: any) => object
        large: (theme: any) => object
    }
    type variantsType = {
        [k in keyof variantsKeys]: variantsKeys[k]
    }
    const variants: variantsType = {
        small: (theme: any) => ({
            tile: Object.assign({
                minWidth: theme.spacing(10),
                height: theme.spacing(10),
                background: grey[500],
                position: 'relative',
                '&:hover': {
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }
            }, colorMap[color].tile),
            content: {
                fontSize: '2rem',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            title: {
                textTransform: 'uppercase'
            },
            icon: {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }
        }),
        default: (theme: any) => ({
            tile: Object.assign({
                minWidth: theme.spacing(15),
                height: theme.spacing(15),
                position: 'relative',
                '&:hover': {
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }
            }, colorMap[color].tile),
            content: {
                fontSize: '2rem',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            title: {
                textTransform: 'uppercase'
            },
            icon: {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }
        }),
        big: (theme: any) => ({
            tile: Object.assign({
                minWidth: theme.spacing(20),
                height: theme.spacing(20),
                position: 'relative',
                '&:hover': {
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }
            }, colorMap[color].tile),
            content: {
                fontSize: '2rem',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            title: {
                textTransform: 'uppercase'
            },
            icon: {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }
        }),
        large: (theme: any) => ({
            tile: Object.assign({
                minWidth: theme.spacing(25),
                height: theme.spacing(25),
                position: 'relative',
                '&:hover': {
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }
            }, colorMap[color].tile),
            content: {
                fontSize: '2rem',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            title: {
                textTransform: 'uppercase'
            },
            icon: {
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }
        })
    }

    return makeStyles(variants[variant])
}

type BigTileProps = {
    color?: 'default' | 'grey' | 'green' | 'blue' | 'teal',
    variant?: 'small' | 'default' | 'big' | 'large',
    width?: string, // 15px , 10rem etc
    height?: string, // 15px , 10rem etc
    title?: string,
    content?: string
    icon?: React.FC | React.ReactElement
}

const PosedPaper = posed(Paper)({
    onHover: {
        scale: 1.05
    },
    none: {
        scale: 1
    }
})

const BigTile: React.FC<BigTileProps> = ({
    variant = 'default',
    color = 'default',
    width,
    height,
    children,
    title,
    content,
    icon,
    ...props
}) => {
    const [hover, setHover] = React.useState(false)
    const useStyles = styleProducer(variant, color)
    const classes = useStyles()
    const onHoverHandle = (bool: boolean) => () => {
        setHover(bool)
    }
    const style = {height, width}
    if (!height) delete style['height']
    if (!width) delete style['width']

    return (

        <PosedPaper className={classes.tile} style={{ height, width }} pose={hover ? 'onHover' : 'none'} onMouseEnter={onHoverHandle(true)} onMouseLeave={onHoverHandle(false)}>
            <Box className={classes.icon} p={1}>
                {icon}
            </Box>
            <Box height="100%" width="100%" display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" flexDirection="column">
                <Box mb={1} className={classes.content}>{children ? children : content}</Box>
                <div className={classes.title}>{title}</div>
            </Box>
        </PosedPaper>
    )
}
export default BigTile
```

And here is my test :

```
    it('BigTile hover check', ()=>{
        const { container } = render(<BigTile />)
        const elem = container.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.MuiPaper-root')
        if (!elem) fail("Element is null.")
        fireEvent.mouseOver(elem);
        const elemAfterHover = container.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.MuiPaper-root')
        if (!elemAfterHover) fail("Element after hover is null.")
        console.log(elemAfterHover.style)
    })
```

Here i cant see changed style after mouseover event. Console log shows me only transform:none
when it should be something like transform: scale(1.05).
Please help me with firing this event properly and if you have some advise to the code itself it would be great to take some advices.

Answer (score 0):

//Answer

The event was firing every time i started the test.
To check it i just put some console.log(..) inside onHoverHandle which is firing after moseenter/leave.

Of course i didn't need to find element once again after fireEvent, becouse i had this element before. Main idea is that i needed to wait for event to end before checking for style change. So waitFor is good for that.
I read somewhere than using userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event' is better than fireEvent , so i did.

Final solution :

```
    it('BigTile hover check.', async ()=>{
        const { container } = render(<BigTile />)
        const elem = container.firstChild as HTMLElement
        if (!elem) fail("Element is null.")
        userEvent.hover(elem);
        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(elem.style.transform).toEqual("scale(1.05) translateZ(0)")
        })
    })
```